# User Perspective (Clipped). What does the clipped mean?

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools, snapping

It's the first time I see this and I'm quite sure it's something really simple, but I don't know how to fix it. I probably mispressed a key or something.

[image]

What's bugging me here is the text that says `Clipped`. I don't know what it means but it's the first time I see it and I have no idea about how to enable/disable it. Somehow, though, since it's appeared, I can't use snapping anymore unless I activate X-ray mode and it also prevents me from selecting some faces with the border select tool.

Does anyone here knows what it means and how to enable/disable it?

Thanks in advance.

Blend file is here if needed :

[image]

Comment: Just to add that I was unable to select any faces of an object when being on Clipped mode, everything looked pretty much normal, so keep an eye for the (Clipped)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point in your Blender file your probably Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>B</kbd> and them selected an area to view. What this does is that it "clips" the area outside fo the perspective projection that you selected.

To get rid of this simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>B</kbd> again.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew about this already but it completely got out of my mind. Thank you thank you thank you